# using .ContinueWith in Non Async Controller

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2, task-parallel-library, task

I am struggling to understand how Task.ContinueWith is supposed to work in Asp.Net WebApi. I wonder if someone can explain how, given the example below.

Consider the following example:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    DoStuff()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            _log.Debug("Log some stuff");
        });

    return Ok();
}

public async Task DoStuff()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

From what I have read I was expecting the continuation function to execute (even when the web request has completed), but it never does. If I reduce the Task.Delay down to <10ms it works. I assume that when the web request returns, the continuation function is "lost", but why is that, is it not just a piece of work waiting to be completed on a ThreadPool thread???

Please help! Thanks..

Comment: You need to `.Wait()` after the `ContinueWith` since it also returns a `Task`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Sunshine Do I have to `.Wait()` though? In this case, I'd like to return the web request and let the `Task` continue it's work and the `.ContinueWith()` also.

Comment: `async` tasks are not meant for use in parallelism like this. The task is attached to the request threads context, so when the request thread is returned to the pool, the Task is canceled. You should look into something like the QueueBackgroundWorkItem https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx if you want a background task to run outside the request thread.

Comment: @Sunshine, thanks for reply. I have not seen any info saying that "the attached task is attached to the request threads context". Can you point me in the right direction? If that's the case, that makes complete sense. Thanks for the info on, QueueBackgroundWorkItem, I will take a look at now.

Comment: Just change the method signature to `async Task<IHttpActionResult>`.  There are no separate asynchronous controllers, the same controller base class handles actions whether they have the `async` keyword or not. *Why* do you want to avoid it? What is the *real* problem you want to solve and why do you think that you need to avoid async methods to do it?

Comment: IIS, ASP.NET, Web API  all use threadpool threads. Once a request finishes ASP.NET/IIS are free to abort any background threads and put them back to the thread pool.

Comment: @user644698: Never use `ContinueWith`. Whatever problem you're trying to solve has a better solution than that.